# `INTERSECT` does not return anything from two tables, separately values are returned fine

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here since I didn't touch SQL queries for several years plus MSSQL query language is a bit strange to me but after 30 minutes of googling I still cannot find the answer.

#### Problem

I have two queries that work perfectly fine:

- `SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NumberOfAccounts' FROM Accounts`
- `SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NumberOfUsers' FROM Users`

I need to get this information in one go in my API response since I don't want to execute two statements. How can I combine them into one query so it will return table as follows:

```
+------------------+---------------+
| NumberOfAccounts | NumberOfUsers |
+------------------+---------------+
|               10 |            16 |
+------------------+---------------+
```

#### What I have tried

1. **UNION** `SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NumberOfAccounts' FROM Accounts UNION SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NumberOfUsers' FROM Users`

This is giving me the result of both tables, however it all pushes it into `NumberOfAccounts` and the result is invalid for me to parse.

```
+------------------+
| NumberOfAccounts |
+------------------+
|               10 |
|               16 |
+------------------+
```

2. **INTRSECT** `SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NumberOfAccounts' FROM Accounts INTERSECT SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NumberOfUsers' FROM Users`

This just gives me empty result with only `NumberOfAccounts` column in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just put these as subqueries in a `select`:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Accounts) as NumberOfAccounts,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users) as NumberOfUsers
```

In SQL Server, no `FROM` clause is needed.

Comment: Your answer is better than my one :-D

Comment: Thank all you for the answers but I think this is the simplest one. Thanks Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` is the wrong usage here. [Union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) will "merge" rows of identical tables (or identical selects) and not columns.

One solution might be:

```
SELECT AccountCount, UserCount FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS AccountCount, 1 AS Id FROM Accounts) AS a 
JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS UserCount, 1 as Id FROM Users) AS u ON (a.Id = u.Id)
```

Be aware of the artificial surrogate key `1` you need to insert to [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) both sub-selects together.

Comment: You can simply CROSS JOIN instead.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake; with `UNION ALL` you'd do:

```
SELECT 'NumberOfAccounts' AS what, COUNT(*) AS howmany FROM accounts
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NumberOfUsers' AS what, COUNT(*) AS howmany FROM users;
```

which results in

```
+------------------+---------+
| what             | howmany |
+------------------+---------+
| NumberOfAccounts |      10 |
| NumberOfUsers    |      16 |
+------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

And another variation:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntAccounts, 0 AS cntUsers FROM accounts
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 0 AS cntAccounts, COUNT(*) AS cntUsers FROM users
 )
SELECT
   SUM(cntAccounts) AS NumberOfAccounts
  ,SUM(cntUsers ) AS NumberOfUsers
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want (need) better performance you can get the row counts from the following query which uses sys.dm_db_partition_stats to get the row counts:

```
SELECT  (
            SELECT  SUM (row_count)
            FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats
            WHERE   object_id=OBJECT_ID('Accounts')   
                    AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1)) NumberOfAccounts,
        (
            SELECT  SUM (row_count)
            FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats
            WHERE   object_id=OBJECT_ID('Users')   
                    AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1)) NumberOfUsers
```

Comment: No. From the docs: "row_count - bigint - The **approximate** number of rows in the partition". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql

Comment: Seems to be accurate according to this post and my experience with it: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/67624/ It can be a real life saver on very large tables.